# i am trying to make a photo gallery like app but i am getting clamp target GC heap from 128MB to 128MB when i am adding bitmap object to arraylist

Tags: android, bitmap

the for loop work for 7 times but after it the app crash.in the memory graph it shows the level at 124mb.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {      
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_first);

    String path=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
    File direct = new File(path);
    File[] dirFiles=direct.listFiles();

    ArrayList<Bitmap> arr= new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i=0 ; i < dirFiles.length;i++){    
        Bitmap myBitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dirFiles[i].getAbsolutePath());     
        arr.add(myBitmap);            
        Log.v("image number",""+i);        
     } 

    //ImageAdapter imgAdp = new ImageAdapter(this,arr);

    //ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.rootView);

    //lv.setAdapter(imgAdp);
}
```

Comment: "Gallery" apps do not all of the bitmaps into memory at once at full resolution. You will not have enough memory for that. Use an image-loading library (e.g., Glide, Picasso) that can scale down the images to better fit your desired `ImageViews` and can load the images as needed by your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a image caching library like [Android-Universal-Image-Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) instead of adding all the bitmaps to a arraylist
This is how you'd use it with files

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.decode(Uri.fromFile(new File(pathToFile)).toString()),   viewHolder.svg,options);}});
```